# Insufficient permissions to trash a message via the Gmail API

Tags: python, debugging, google-oauth, gmail-api

My code should take a message in my inbox, check it for a link and then pull the link from the email and then trash it.

```
message = gmail_service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=thread['id'], format='raw').execute()    #get message using thread id
msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
for part in msg.walk():
    msg.get_payload()
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
        mytext = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(part.get_payload().encode('UTF-8'))
        html = BeautifulSoup(mytext)
        for link in html.find_all('a'):
            mylink = link.get('href')
            print mylink
            try:
                service.users().messages().trash(userId='me', id=thread['id']).execute()
                print 'Message with id: %s trashed successfully.' % msg_id
            except errors.HttpError, error:
                print 'Could not trash ' + thread['id'] + ': %s' % error
```

The scope I have defined in my code is `.modify` which should give me the permissions I need to trash a message [without fail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/trash). Why am I getting the error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/147d8c9a6348e437/trash?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

**Edit:** Even the [documented example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/trash) returns a 403 forbidden error, this must be a bug with the Gmail API itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At some point in the past, you registered with readonly scope in the same directory, and this was cached in the file called gmail.storage.

Move that file out of the way and run your program again and it should work.

Comment: Where/what is the gmail.storage file?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the token.pickle file. It will regenerate after you run your code. When you run the code a browser window will pop-up to authorize permission for your account and the app you are using. Just like when you did the 'quickstart' code.